# Pandas str replace dropping entire value instead of replacing

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, replace

There is a behaviour and I don't understand why it is happening.

```
# Make a dataframe with a column of floats
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1'])
df.loc[0] = 10.0
df.loc[1] = 5.0
df.loc[2] = 6.0
df.loc[3] = 20.0

# Convert the column to string
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)

# Use .str.replace to replace the decimal points of .0 with nothing
df['col1'].str.replace('.0', '')
```

But this returns an empty string for the first and last value 
0     
1    5
2    6
3     
Name: col1, dtype: object

However doing this:

```
# Apply replace in a lambda function
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.0', ''))
```

And this returns the expected results 
0    10
1     5
2     6
3    20
Name: col1, dtype: object

Is it something to do with it confusing 0.0 with .0?

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Because `.` is special regex character is necessry escape it or add `regex=False`:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.replace('\.0', '', regex=True)
df['col3'] = df['col1'].str.replace('.0', '', regex=False)
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3
0  10.0   10   10
1   5.0    5    5
2   6.0    6    6
3  20.0   20   20
```

Comment: That makes sense! The difference between the two is the Pandas str.replace function accepts regex, whereas the standard string replace function doesn't